# Icon (DefaultIcon) is displayed differently

Tags: windows, icons, registry, file-association

I'm struggling with the icon of my application's document files.
First, I'm registering the file extension:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.Ext\(default) = AppName
```

Then I give it a shell open command and a icon:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[AppName]\shell\open\command\(default)="path\app.exe"
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\[AppName]\DefaultIcon\(default)="path\app.exe",0
```

The icon is displayed in Explorer, but not the original one, instead it displays it on a white sheet:

[image]

The left one is the associated file, the right one is the executable.

How do I set the registry entries to get the original icon displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if `DefaultIcon` supports quotes on the path, other than that the registration looks OK.

After writing these entries you should call `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, 0, 0)` so other applications can refresh themselves.

The document icon is generated by the shell (`GIL_SIMULATEDOC`) when it cannot find a valid  `DefaultIcon` entry but it knows which executable it is going to use. This can happen if you use "Open With" to open your file-type when it has no registration.

Try calling `SHChangeNotify` and then reboot. If that does not fix it then you should search the registry for your file extension and remove it from Explorers HKCU `FileExts` key**s** and any "auto" entries for your type in HKCR. Clearing the shell iconcache might also help.

Comment: I actually call `SHChangeNotify` exactly as you mentioned, sorry for hiding this. The method which does the whole thing works perfect on two another file extensions. So it seems that you are correct - maybe I hit "Open with" some day.   
The ugly thing is that it can't be repaired with the current implementation. Do you have any hint for that? Somewhere there must be a cache?

Comment: First you should try registering the application on a fresh machine (and if you don't have access to one, at least try a different user account), and if it does not work then there is a problem with the registration (path? quotes?). They way Explorer handles things is not documented but you can try what I already suggested: Look for your extension in the "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts" key and any "%yourext%_auto_file" keys in HKCR and delete them. If your extension is unique then you can uninstall your app and then search for keys/values you did not create.

Answer (score 0):

One part of your question was not covered by the answers so far: Why is your icon displayed on a white sheet and not alone, as you expected? Under Windows 7 I have observed that this is standard behaviour: it happens even for Word documents and Excel spreadsheets. But I have found that I can defeat it, and force the icon to be displayed alone, if the .ico file specified for DefaultIcon contains only images of size 16, 32, 48 and 256. This is what Windows 7 does for GIF files, for example, which use "C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll,-71" for their DefaultIcon, which is an icon group of only these sizes.